# Defining django models in an alphabetic order

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-3.4

Can I define django models in an alphabetic order?

Models taken from [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/):

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I'd like for `Choice` to be defined before the `Question`. After simple reordering

```
class Choice(models.Models):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Question(models.Models):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Fails, because I need `Question` before telling interpreter what it is.

Adding simple empty

```
class Choise(models.Model): pass
class Question(models.Model): pass
```

causes django to scream and still fail `python manage.py makemigrations polls`.

Is there a hack to define models in alphabetical order?

Or should I forfeit this idea and just define from totally unrelks ated to related to everything?

NOTE:
according to Sayse, the workarounds break IDEs in that IDE can't know whether you mean literal string or if you are looking for a class.

Comment: Honestly, I would forfeit the idea, whilst it is possible. Its doesn't really benefit you all that much and can make refactoring harder

Comment: Why would it make refactoring harder? Because following relationships is harder?

Comment: Normally, you can just right click a class name and choose to refactor it, if its looking for a string it has no idea if you have a string with the text `Question` or if this is in fact your model

Comment: I guess, vim does not have that capability, so I haven't thought of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself:

```
question = models.ForeignKey('Question')
```

instead of

```
question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Answer (score 3):

You can reference a model that has not been yet declared using quotes:

```
class Choice(models.Models):
    question = models.ForeignKey('Question')
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Question(models.Models):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Comment: Note:This does make it harder for refactoring, however.

Comment: Possibly. Can't see any other way though to fulfil the strange requirement of alphabetic ordering.